# Invalid constant value. on _isElevated

Tags: flutter, dart

boxShadow:**_isElevated** ?[
BoxShadow(
color: Colors.grey,
spreadRadius: 1,
blurRadius: 15,
offset: Offset(4, 4)
),
]:null,

Comment: To answer this question, more context is needed. Please check [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

you have a const on something you didn't put in the question.  Since the boxShadow is conditional, shouldn't have a const.